# Could not install Maven plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I am trying to install `maven` plugin to eclipse luna.
Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)

I followed below steps,
Help>Install New Software.

Added URL in work with - http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Selected all maven integration for eclipse.

Then click next, accepted licence agreement and finish.

but after this getting error

```
        An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
    session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.6.2.20150902-0001
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.discovery,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.launching,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.6.2.20150902-0001
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.6.2.20150902-0001
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple,1.6.2.20150902-0001
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.scm,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.feature,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature,1.6.2.20150902-0002
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.workspace.cli,0.3.1
```

I have many plugins already installed like SVN, ant, testng, etc. But could not proceed with `maven`. Also tried with eclipse market-place but facing same error. Graceful anyone can help.

Comment: is your eclipse properly able to connect to internet ? ...check your proxy settings...you can test by opening a browser inside eclipse and firing a web request

Comment: Yes it is connected.. Also checked proxy setting and they are OK. Also open url in eclipse browser and working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this issue. I have used eclipse Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1). Yet I don't know what the problem was but I downloaded latest eclipse Luna and then added required plugins. It was successfully installed. Then I have import my projects to new work-space with new eclipse . Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to paste the following link `https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/latest` and everything would work.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34972630)